# Single cell array for vba TTest

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a `TTest` which requires me to compare one mean of ranges to another.

However, my excel file is populated by means already, so I do not need to average ranges as excel is forcing me to.

Is there any way that I can get the `TTest` function to think that I am feeding it a multicell range even though it is only getting the data from a single cell for each variable in the ttest?

Right now I have it set as a range, but if under `Range("A1:A2")` I change it to `Range("A1")` it no longer will work. Thanks!

```
Sub a()

Dim Z As Double

Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("A1:A2")

Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = Range("B1:B2")

Z = Application.WorksheetFunction.TTest(rng1, rng2, 2, 1)

MsgBox "value is " & Z

End Sub
```

Comment: No. The t-test divides the difference between the means of two sample or population data sets by a factor that pools the standard deviations of each data set. The standard deviation of a single number (here, the average) is zero, hence you get a divide by zero error. See [**this article**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test) for the definition of this statistic.

Comment: To put what chuff said more simply, Excel can not perform a t-test without all the underlying data.  If A1 has the formula for the average you could use range("a1").formula to get the literal string of the formula and parse out the range.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using ranges? Try defining the arrays explicitly a la '=TTEST({23,25,28},{33,35,37},1,1)"